# Separar CSV en varios filtrando por una columna

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un software para separar un archivo CSV en varios archivos CSV, filtrando por una columna.
Yo importo el archivo y lo pongo en un GridView y después quiero escoger la columna de filtro (en el ejemplo "PartRemark2").
Luego poner todos items con el mismo valor en un nuevo archivo CSV.
Por ejemplo todas lineas que en la columna "PartRemark2" tienen el valor "MDF 16mm AN" en un archivo y todas lineas que tengan "MDF 16mm BL" en otro.
Cual seria la mejor manera de hacer esto?
Piense en hacer un Array con el contenido de la columna "PartRemark2" sin repetir y después hacer in IF y/o FOREACH para crear los archivos.
[[image: Pantalla software con GridView de ejemplo]]

Comment: Y cual es el problema con el codigo que estas comentando? no anda? Cuando decis cual seria la mejor manera, tenes que especificar la mejor manera para conseguir tal resultado (mas velocidad? menos codigo?) ademas debes mostrar lo que ya probaste, y porque crees que esa no es la mejor manera. Cualquier forma que lo hagas va a estar bien, si resuelve el problema.

Comment: La verdad aun no hice ninguno codigo, mi duda es si tengo que crear un Array con el contenido de la columna que quiero hacer el filtro o si hay una manera de leer el contenido y ya guardar en el archivo CSV con el mismo contenido de la columna de filtro(PartRemark2).

Comment: Para ya hacer el código de la forma mas eficiente con menos procesos, menos memoria y menos código.

Comment: En realidad lo que pedis es lo que deseamos todos. Pero de la forma redactada, esta pidiendo que te escribamos el codigo. Te invito a hacer una prueba, y despues escribir tu resultado en esta pregunta y trabajar desde alli.

Comment: Lo mas eficiente en términos de performance es usar StreamReader para leer, StreamWritter para grabar y StringBuilder para concatenar strings. Si lo que quieres es poco código entonces usa la clase File de .Net. Pero si hablamos de CSV hay muy buenas librerías que puedes usar, como CsvHelper o la clase TextFieldParser de .Net. Los ejemplos están fáciles de seguir.

Comment: Ok, gracias, voy buscar estudiar sobre esto.